# Parsing HTTP 202 with an empty payload - java.io.EOFException - Android, Retrofit, Gson

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

The idea: There's an endpoint I'm trying to consume on Android. After calling it, the endpoint will return HTTP 202 (empty body, there's no payload at all) for a couple of times and when the data is ready it will return HTTP 200 with the data.

What I want to do is be able to parse the 202 response, but since it does not have a payload I'll just check the status and poll again if needed and once I get the 200 OK, I'll parse and use the data.

The part where I parse and use the 200 OK response is working, but parsing the 202 response does not work, I get the Exception (see below).

I know there are several approaches to this:

- using Void as the return type,
- using ResponseBody as the return type,
- using a Converter.Factory.

I've created a converter class for this:

```
internal val nullOnEmptyConverterFactory = object : Converter.Factory() {
    fun converterFactory() = this
    override fun responseBodyConverter(
        type: Type,
        annotations: Array<out Annotation>,
        retrofit: Retrofit
    ) = object : Converter<ResponseBody, Any?> {
        val nextResponseBodyConverter =
            retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter<Any?>(converterFactory(), type, annotations)

        override fun convert(value: ResponseBody) =
            if (value.contentLength() != 0L) nextResponseBodyConverter.convert(value) else null
    }
}
```

This is how I use it:

```
return Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(nullOnEmptyConverterFactory)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()) // used for jsonp
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(factory))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .baseUrl(ApiService.getBaseUrl())
            .build()
```

And this is the error I get:

```
error: java.io.EOFException
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.require(RealBufferedSource.kt:55)
        at okio.GzipSource.consumeHeader(GzipSource.kt:104)
        at okio.GzipSource.read(GzipSource.kt:62)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.kt:41)
        at okio.ForwardingSource.read(ForwardingSource.kt:29)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$ExceptionCatchingResponseBody$1.read(OkHttpCall.java:288)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.select(RealBufferedSource.kt:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.Util.readBomAsCharset(Util.kt:256)
        at okhttp3.ResponseBody$BomAwareReader.read(ResponseBody.kt:208)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:1295)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1333)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.consumeNonExecutePrefix(JsonReader.java:1576)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:534)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:207)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:39)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
        at data.network.util.NullOnEmptyConverterFactoryKt$nullOnEmptyConverterFactory$1$responseBodyConverter$1.convert(NullOnEmptyConverterFactory.kt:22)
        at data.network.util.NullOnEmptyConverterFactoryKt$nullOnEmptyConverterFactory$1$responseBodyConverter$1.convert(NullOnEmptyConverterFactory.kt:17)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:225)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what caused this: none of the libraries mentioned above, Retrofit, GSon are at fault. If you follow the stack trace you'll see that it points to a problem, that the response does not conform to the gzip file format.

The OkHttp library expects the response to have a 10 byte header, if you're using gzip file format. If the response does not have it, the lib throws an exception.

The API is at fault in this case.

[The ticket](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3646) that helped me figure out the isse.